# Ormlite with Firebird fail on keyword fields

Tags: c#, sql, firebird, ormlite-servicestack

This is my problem. I work with Ormlite (ServiceStack) on Firebird database. Unfortunately I inherited database structure with column name which is keyword - FUNCTION:

```
CREATE TABLE CONTACT (
    ID_CONTACT      TID NOT NULL,
    CLIENT_ID       TID NOT NULL,
    NAME            VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PHONE           VARCHAR(50),
    EMAIL           VARCHAR(200),
    "FUNCTION"      VARCHAR(60), -- this column causes problem
    CREATED_DATE    DATE,
   MODIFIED_DATE    DATE,
 );
```

When I run Ormlite code like this: _db.Insert(contactDb) – where contactDb is POCO object I got sql error because database server needs parenthesis around column FUNCTION and Ormlite doesn’t put it. 
I tried with aliases:

```
 [Alias("FUNCTION")]
 public string Function { get; set;}
```

or

```
 [Alias("\"FUNCTION\"")]
 public string Function { get; set;}
```

with no success.

Firebird has dialect version 3. I cannot simply change column name. What can I do?

Comment: I also tried QuoteNames property of FirebirdOrmLiteDialectProvider but nothing changes.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the [sourcecode of the dialect](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird/FirebirdOrmLiteDialectProvider.cs) it should quote it.

Comment: Its a pity but no - this is sql generated by LiteOrm:

INSERT INTO CONTACT (ID_CONTACT,CLIENT_ID,NAME,TELEPHONE,CELL_PHONE,EMAIL,FUNCTION,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,MODIFIED_DATE,HISTORY,COMMENTS) VALUES (@ID_CONTACT,@CLIENT_ID,@NAME,@TELEPHONE,@CELL_PHONE,@EMAIL,@FUNCTION,@CREATED_BY,@CREATED_DATE,@MODIFIED_DATE,@HISTORY,@COMMENTS)

Comment: Then I guess it is a bug and you should report it to ServiceStack.